# Open Hamiltonian Gromov-Witten Invariants

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-topology, equivariant-cohomology

Both open Gromov-Witten invariants and Hamiltonian Gromov-Witten invariants have been studied. I am interested in knowing whether anyone has considered open Hamiltonian Gromov-Witten invariants before. I believe they should be defined (for some symplectic manifold $X$) with respect to the moduli space of some kind of vortex equations on a disk whose boundary intersects (some generalization of) a Lagrangian submanifold on $X$. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: See the work of Seidel et al. related to open-closed maps.

Comment: Thank you. Could you add a specific reference?